# Limiting FPS in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

Can I set a maximum fps? Is there any way to limit fps in andengine?
I thought it was quite easy, but I could not find how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

Instead of `new Engine(...)`, use `new LimitedFPSEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions, int pFramesPerSecond);`.